# Is it possible to have alias for dict row in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I think that answer is no, but would like to ask for future generations :-)

Today I found interesting bug in my codebase.

Here is some context:

```
>>> d1={1:[1], 2:[2], 3:[3]}    ### in practice I have more complex data but [] is correct
>>> a1=d1[2]                    ### I wanted to use a1 as alias, in 15x places 
>>> id(d1)
4503224000
>>> id(a1)
4504750528
>>> id(d1[2])
4504750528
>>> d1
{1: [1], 2: [2], 3: [3]}
>>> a1
[2]
>>> a1[0] = 22                  ### this also correct, I know it is hack
>>> d1                          ### value is original dict is changed
{1: [1], 2: [22], 3: [3]}
>>> a1                  
[22]
>>> del a1                      ### now I want to delete it 
>>> a1                          ### it is deleted 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a1' is not defined
>>> d1                          ### but not in original dict
{1: [1], 2: [22], 3: [3]}
>>> del d1[2]                   ### must be deleted directly 
>>> d1
{1: [1], 3: [3]}
```

I understand what is happening and why.

But am curious is there way to make a1 as alias to original d1[2] so when del a1 is done it is same as del d1[2] ?

P.S. I have this idea because of my bad influence from C/C++.

Comment: All that `del(foo)` does is to remove the name `foo` from an object. This will not affect any other references to the same object. It is not the same as `del(bar[baz])` which is to delete the item `baz` from the object `bar` for those objects that support item deletion (although that also will not affect any other references). In both cases, this will decrease the reference count to the object by 1, and if that was the last reference to it then the object itself will be destroyed.

Comment: In particular, `del(bar[baz])` will call `bar.__delitem__(baz)`. It is an in-place modification to mutable object `bar`, so is completely different from de-assigning a name, even though the syntax is (possibly confusingly) somewhat similar.

Comment: @alaniwi Can you use del as a function?

Comment: @RobKwasowski No, `del` is a keyword not an object. Trying to call it will give a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @RobKwasowski However, `my_dictionary.__delitem__` certainly _can_ be used as a function.

Comment: @alaniwi So you're saying del(baz) is incorrect? Because that's what you've put

Comment: @RobKwasowski In my example, `baz` is a variable containing a key of dictionary `bar`. If you did `del(baz)` rather than `del(bar[baz])` you would simply destroy the `baz` string variable and have no effect on the dictionary `bar` itself.

Comment: @alaniwi My point is you said del is not a function but you're calling it as a function

Comment: @RobKwasowski Okay, sorry, my use of parentheses probably did not add clarity, although it is syntactically permitted. In either case, with or without parentheses, it is a keyword, and not an object. For example, trying to assign it to a variable (`a = del`) would give a syntax error.